# If two numbers of a field produce a number that is not in that field, is it suitable to call that number system a field?

Tags: field-theory

To elaborate the question- I've heard that natural numbers themselves can't form a field. Because when I consider two natural numbers 2 and 3, through division I get 2/3, a number that is not defined in natural number system. Similarly √(2) is not defined in the rational number system, even though 2 is defined in the rational system. So is it suitable to call rational number system a field?

Comment: The word “field” has a precise definition. Anything that satisfies that definition, such as the rational numbers but not the natural numbers, is a field.

Comment: Please read the first paragraph of the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) for fields. It says: "In mathematics, a field is a set on which addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division are defined and behave as the corresponding operations on rational and real numbers do." Later it is elaborated there exactly what it means to "behave as the corresponding operations on rational and real numbers do", but already here you see there is no mention of taking square roots. Fields are closed under the $4$ operations $+,-,\cdot,/$.

Comment: The notion of a field closed also under taking square roots is called a [quadratically closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_closed_field).

Comment: A field must be closed in two operations, that's it ! There are fields behaving "better" like the algebraic closed fields like $\mathbb C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot divide two natural numbers. Division is a not well-defined concept for the semiring of natural numbers $(\mathbb{N},0_{\mathbb{N}},1_{\mathbb{N}},+_{\mathbb{N}},\cdot_{\mathbb{N}}).$ Yes, you can talk about **divisibility** as a property of natural numbers, but not as an operation of natural numbers. For division to be an operation, you require the concept of a multiplicative inverse, which this semiring does not have, in general. The division of $2_{\mathbb{N}}=1_{\mathbb{N}}+_{\mathbb{N}}1_{\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $3_{\mathbb{N}}=1_{\mathbb{N}}+_{\mathbb{N}}1_{\mathbb{N}}+_{\mathbb{N}}1_{\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{N}$ is not $2_{\mathbb{N}}/3_{\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{Q}.$ The division is simply undefined.

Now, division is defined for the rational numbers, because the rational numbers form a field $(\mathbb{Q},0_{\mathbb{Q}},1_{\mathbb{Q}},+_{\mathbb{Q}},\cdot_{\mathbb{Q}}).$ As such, you can indeed say that if you divide $2_{\mathbb{Q}}=1_{\mathbb{Q}}+_{\mathbb{Q}}1_{\mathbb{Q}}\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $3_{\mathbb{Q}}=1_{\mathbb{Q}}+_{\mathbb{Q}}1_{\mathbb{Q}}+_{\mathbb{Q}}1_{\mathbb{Q}}\in\mathbb{Q},$ then you do get $2_{\mathbb{Q}}/3_{\mathbb{Q}}\in\mathbb{Q}.$

Your confusion originates from the fact that you are thinking that $2_{\mathbb{N}}=2_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $3_{\mathbb{N}}=3_{\mathbb{N}}.$ This confusion is understandable: in practice, we never write the subscripts, we just write $2$ and $3$ respectively, further suggesting that the above equalities do hold. But that is not actually the case. The structures $(\mathbb{N},0_{\mathbb{N}},1_{\mathbb{N}},+_{\mathbb{N}},\cdot_{\mathbb{N}})$ and $(\mathbb{Q},0_{\mathbb{Q}},1_{\mathbb{Q}},+_{\mathbb{Q}},\cdot_{\mathbb{Q}})$ are different. $0_{\mathbb{N}}$ is the additive identity element of $\mathbb{N},$ not of $\mathbb{Q}.$ This is why I am using subscripts in this post. **HOWEVER,** the structure $(\mathbb{N},0_{\mathbb{N}},1_{\mathbb{N}},+_{\mathbb{N}},\cdot_{\mathbb{N}})$ can be embedded in the structure $(\mathbb{Q},0_{\mathbb{Q}},1_{\mathbb{Q}},+_{\mathbb{Q}},\cdot_{\mathbb{Q}}),$ which is a jargon-heavy way of saying that the latter is an extension of the former in some natural sense. As such, there is a natural sense in which $0_{\mathbb{N}}$ *corresponds* to $0_{\mathbb{Q}}$ in this extension, and analogously, $1_{\mathbb{N}}$ corresponds to $1_{\mathbb{Q}},$ and the operations $+_{\mathbb{N}},\cdot_{\mathbb{N}}$ properly extend to $+_{\mathbb{Q}},\cdot_{\mathbb{Q}}.$ And because which of the two structures is being aluded to is typically clear from context, we just omit the subscripts, and write $0,1,+,\cdot$ for both structures, since writing the subscripts makes the notation extremely cumbersome, and this omission is justified by the above fact: that one structure is simple a natural extension of the other, in some rigorous sense.

As such, it is important to keep in mind that whenever anyone talks about dividing $2$ and $3,$ we are talking about the rational numbers $2_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $3_{\mathbb{Q}},$ and never the natural numbers $2_{\mathbb{N}}$ and $2_{\mathbb{N}}.$ The concept of division does not exist for the natural numbers. It only exists for the algebraic structures that we call fields.